# Does inserting the first ACL rule remove the implicit "to less secure" ACL rule?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Each interface on a Cisco ASA has a security level. By default the ASA ACL allows traffic from higher to lower security level, but not the other way around.

Question: When I add an additional ACL rule, does the implicit rule still apply if my inserted rule doesn't match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, specific rule takes the implicit ANY->ANY LESS SECURE rule down. If your rule is not matched, the packet will proceed to the implicit DENY.